Installing MacTex on new machine -- where do my .cls and .sty files go?
I'm setting up MacTeX on a new machine (M2 MacBook, Sonoma 14.4) and I can't find where I'm supposed to drop my .cls and .sty files. On the old machine I had them in /Users/me/Library/texmf/tex/latex, but that path doesn't seem to exist on the new machine. Under /Users/me/Library there's only a directory for TexShop (which I don't use), and under /Library/TeX I can't find a texmf directory, though I do see texmf-var etc. What

All you have to do is create /Users/me/Library/texmf/tex/latex on the new Mac. Or, you can use AirDrop to copy it over from the old Mac.

You can always find the correct location on the command line using
    kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME

If your shell is sufficiently bash-like or zsh-like (as the default shell on a Mac is, for example), you can just say
    mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/mystuff

or whatever location you prefer to mystuff. This will be correct for .cls and .sty files. If you have other files you need to install, you may need to adjust the path for the appropriate filetype.

When I use that kpsewhich command, the answer I get is /Users/me/Library/texmf, but when I type ls /Users/me/Library, or even ls -A /Users/me/Library, texmf doesn't appear. I can certainly create that path, but what is going on?

@crmdgn that's normal. the installer doesn't create it. hence the mkdir command. not everyone uses it. not everyone on your machine may even use the mactex install, after all.
